# Doesnt load app.js after upgrading php 8.0 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

after i upgrade project php version 7.3 to 8.0.0.
when i am importing assets from /dist/js/app.js then i got this error in console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+001F
```

When i look on that file in app.js so it prepend this text before webpack compilaction.

```
‹���������������HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Date: Sun, 27 Dec 2020 08:59:58 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 4219164

/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // install a JSONP callback for chunk loading
/******/    function webpackJsonpCallback(data) {
/******/        var chunkIds = data[0];
/******/        var moreModules = data[1];
/******/
/******/ .. and more compilactioon
```

How can i solve this error? I tried search about this problem, but i didnt found anything.

Comment: Try running `npm run dev` again. The error relates to illegal character in the compiled js file. If it doesn't work remove the node_modules folder `rm -rf node_modules` remove package-lock.json `rm package-lock.json` and then install node dependencies again `npm install`. Once dependencies are installed run `npm run dev` again and check if it works

Comment: Its not error in compilation but probably in php settings. After i switch back to php 7.3 that i dont have this error.

Comment: Sorry I read it as after upgrading from Laravel 7 to LAravel 8 instead of PHP7.3 to PHP 8.0. How are you importing `dist/js/app.js` in your view

Comment: <script src="{{ mix('dist/js/app.js') }}"></script>

Comment: @TomášKudlička what is your Laravel version?

Comment: @thân-lƯƠng 8.0